# Configure X-XSS Protection Header

Tags: http, security, https, xss

I have an Asp.Net website hosted on HTTP. I am currently working on it so that it can support HTTPS Protocol.

Now, as

> HTTP X-XSS-Protection response header is a feature that can stops pages from loading when they detect reflected cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Based on the definition above, I have following questions,

> Knowing that the website will now support HTTPS Protocol, do I still need to configure “X-XSS-Protection” header?

If yes, then,

> How can I configure the HTTP server to return the “X-XSS-Protection” header with every response?.

Answer (score 1):

[X-XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) is a response header that detects *certain* [Cross Site Scripting](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) (XSS) attack attempts. This has no direct relation with the website being served over HTTP or HTTPS.

This header is supported only in Internet Explorer and Safari and doesn't completely eliminate XSS risks from your application. The detection support these headers provide can be easily bypassed and this is not a way to mitigate from XSS attacks.

For XSS Protection,

1. If you use any untrusted user input in your response use a Standard Encoder such as [OWASP Encoder](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-encoder/) contextually.
2. If you want your user input to be rendered as HTML but still want to filter out active javascript elements from your content, use a sanitizer API such as [OWASP Antisamy](https://owasp.org/www-project-antisamy/)
3. As a defense-in-depth technique use [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) Headers to whitelist resource origin and escape from XSS and related attacks.

If you want to still implement a X-XSS-Protection protection, you could refer the first link cited to know allowed values in this response header and their working.